# How can I get access local file form node webkit

Tags: javascript, node-webkit

How can I get access to local resources from node webkit.
I would like to execute this code :

```
script.src = "app://index.html/src/js/test.js"
```

but i get error:

> Not allowed to load local resource: app://index.html/src/js/test.js

Comment: Do you have the correct permissions to read that?

Comment: I don't know. How can I check this?